# Solr search query via PHP cURL

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, curl, solr

I have configured Solr and indexed necessary field values of a MySQL DB though the data import facility provided by the Solr UI.

I queried the necessary text [ by giving a value to the "q" parameter ], it gave me results when using the Solr UI -> Query facility.

It provides a URL where you could directly view the results such as shown below

Eg : //Searching for "Motorbike", this method works

```
http://www.somesite.com/solr/collection1/select?q=Motorbike&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true
```

When I assign the search text to a PHP variable and 
set it as shown below

```
$search_txt = "Motorbike";
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/solr/collection1/select?q=".$search_txt."&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true";
```

But when I try to use cURL to retrieve the result using the url in created as shown in the second method, into my web site it gives me an empty result set. I have no idea why?

Does anyone know why? I'm working on a CodeIgniter project and tried to retrieve the result without trying anything flashy because its a quick way.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that first request find something for you? As far as I know, eDismax parser required qf param, that mean `query fields`

QF param determine which fields are using to searching this query.
For more info please look here - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qf_.28Query_Fields.29

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mysterion, tried that also but the result was the same. 

I tried something like replacing the "^" character with "%5E" through "urlencode" then it gave me results. So I will try by urlencoding the whole string starting from the "q" parameter of the URL and give it a try.

Thanks